# What are the indications of an investigation?

Tags: investigation, crime-network-cosa-nostra

I'm playing *Crime Network: Cosa Nostra*. I like to follow the guidelines in the manual pretty closely, to keep things organized. I'm unclear on how to handle the investigators though and the book doesn't seem to help. When committing a crime, what are the indications of investigation? Does the bureau just send in teams to investigate, directly enter the crime scene, or what?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking here. What do you mean "indications of investigation" and what does "that [they] must communicate" mean?